# Resetting D-Link DGS-3324SR without console access?

Tags: networking, switch

I've gotten hold of a D-Link DGS-3324SR that's going to replace my old dumb switch at home. Problem is that the seller can't remember the passwords, and D-Link give me the backdoor account without some kind of a reciept. Is there a way of resetting this thing without using the backdoor account, or a way to generate the backdoor password? D-Link said that it's a combo of the MAC and possible the name of the switch.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the user manual to the device-
http://www.manualowl.com/m/D-Link/DGS-3324SR/Manual/157365

According to the manual, if you can do a hard reset on the device (by pressing a physical reset button), it should restart with no username or password. pg 25

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. There are no physical reset buttons on this device. I even checked inside for jumpers and whatnot.
Where in the manual did you read this? (It's a beast)

Comment: It talks about the username and password on pg 25

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to reset this device, if you could manage to get it into a Stack as a slave device.

You need another D-Link DGS-3324SR with a higher Mac-Adresse or you have luck and the box priority is higher than your Commander Switch

Answer (score 0):

This is the procedure to reset admin password with physical access to the switch.
[Link to manual page 327](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/419254/D-Link-Dgs-3120-24tc.html?page=327)

Complete these steps to reset the password:

1. For security reasons, the Password Recovery feature requires the user to physically access the device. Therefore this feature is only applicable when there is a direct connection to the console port of the device. It is necessary for the user needs to attach a terminal or PC with terminal emulation to the console port of the switch.
2. Power on the Switch. After the UART init is loaded to 100%, the Switch will allow 2 seconds for the user to press the hotkey [^] (Shift + 6) to enter the "Password Recovery Mode". Once the Switch enters the "Password Recovery Mode," all ports on the Switch will be disabled.

```
Boot Procedure  V1.00.009
_________________________  

  Power On Self Test ........................................ 100% 
  MAC Address  
  : 00-19-5B-EC-32-15  
  H/W Version  
  : A1  
  Please Wait, Loading V1.01.012 Runtime Image .............. 100%   
  UART init ................................................. 100%  
  Password Recovery Mode  
  >
```

In the "Password Recovery Mode" only the following commands can be used.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Start Putty. In the Connection -> Serial settings, specify the COM port that is used for connection (you can see it in the computer device manager), speed 115200, data bits 8, stop bits 1, parity none, flow control xon/xoff. In Terminal -> Keyboard specify VT100+.

Immediately after "Please wait, loading Runtime image ............ 100 %", press shift + 3 (for 2 seconds) and a request "Do you want to load the default configuration? (y/n)" will appear. Press "y" and Enter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).